# Parse css and create key value array of class names and background images

Tags: php, css, regex

If I have css like this:

```
.featured .featured_1 {
    background-image: url("http://test.com/image.png");
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Then this PHP function:

```
function makeArrayOfBackroundImages($css) {
    if (!preg_match_all('/\.([a-z\d_]+)\s*\{[^{}]*url\("?([^()]+)"?\)?/i', $css, $arr)) return array();
return array_combine($arr[1], $arr[2]);
}
```

Creates an array of the class name as the key and the background image as the url.

```
feature => http://test.com/image.png
```

How can I modify the regex and this function so it matches both the class names. In this example there is two classes, but the number of classes will be variable and will be one or more so I will need to match all the class names depending on how many there are. For example I would like to create an array like this so both the class names are listed as key with the background image url as the value for both keys. Ignoring any other css properties in the classes.

```
feature => http://test.com/image.png
featured_1 => http://test.com/image.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I modify the regex and this function so it matches both the class names?

It depends.

Is it always going to be a case where you are matching either one or two? Will there ever be three, four or five?

If it is just two, you can simply repeat the first capture group:

```
\.([a-z\d_]+)\s*(?:\.([a-z\d_]+)\s*)?\{[^{}]*url\("?([^()]+)"?\)?
```

http://regex101.com/r/fC7wU2

Comment: Thanks for this, what if I don't know how many classes will be appended first. It could be one or more. Is there a way to do this?